# How to update, edit, delete, new row in aspx gridview in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, devexpress, aspxgridview

I am very new to ASP.NET MVC 4. I have created one application with MVC4 razor. I need to use devexpress gridview control in application. I have import gridview by right click in view -> installed DevExpress MVC Extension v15.1. UI is working properly. but Now I don't know how to do edit, update, new, delete function work in MVC4 with aspxgridview.

I saw lot of solution on google for webgrid but I need to go with aspxgridview.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you go though DevExpress documentation and examples. Please refer these below links:
[MVC GridView - CRUD operations example](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T157717)
[crud in gridview in asp.net mvc with sql](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T116361)
[GridView - How to implement CRUD operations](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q228328)

Few related one:
[MVC GridView - How to implement CRUD operations with DataTable](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q339856)
[Gridview - How to implement CRUD operations](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T104205)

Hope these help you learn from scratch.